# How do I resize a specific box by css

Tags: html, css

I want to resize to right box whereas left box value (400px) will be fix how do i do that by css? when i resize browser window right box comes down that is not right. here is css and html.

```css
#w {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#left {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#right {
  max-width: 598px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div id="w">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nsrn4hvh/).

Comment: First change your CSS in #right... you cant have width and max-width... chose one and use % not px. Second, use @media queirs to specify when you want the right box to change its size and then style it acordingly...

Comment: wow! Muhammad Usman its working thanks alot

Comment: @weinde Why cant we have width and max-width to an element ? It is possible.

Comment: This might anwser your question: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also please find some piece of information here on using max-width and width to an element https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-width/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```css
.div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.div2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.div3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div4 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h2>Without box-sizing</h2>
<div class="div1">This div is smaller (width is 300px and height is 100px).</div>
<br>
<div class="div2">This div is bigger (width is also 300px and height is 100px).</div>

<h2>With box-sizing</h2>
<div class="div3">Both divs are the same size now!</div>
<br>
<div class="div4">Hooray!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `#left` box with fixed width (in my case width: 400px;) and `#right` box responsive according to screen width using **CSS Flexbox**.

Just as shown in the snippet below:

```css
#left{
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  height:100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#right{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: calc(100% - 405px);
  border:solid 1px #000;
  height:100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Comment: Saurav is it cross browser?

Comment: @zuby Yes! but make sure that it might be buggy in earlier version of IE as IE doesn't fully support CSS Flexbox yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir but ie 9 is not supporting the code.

Answer (score 0):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can make `w` a flexbox and:

1. Give `flex: 1` to `right` for it to self-adjust
2. Add `flex: 0 0 400px` to `left` to keep the width fixed at 400px.

Demo below:

```css
#w {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
#left {
  max-width: 400px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 0 400px;
}
#right {
  max-width: 598px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="w">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#w{
        max-width:1000px;
        white-space: nowrap; 
        border:solid 1px #eee;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        margin:0;     
}
#left{
      display:inline-block;
      max-width:400px;
      width:100%;
      border:solid 1px #000;
      height:100px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
#right{
      display:inline-block; 
      max-width:598px;
      width:100%;
      border:solid 1px #000;
      height:100px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
    <div id="w">
    <div id="left">X</div>
    <div id="right">X</div>
     Tested: Firfox & Chrome browsers!
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

```
   #w {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: solid 1px #eee;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 400px;
    }

    #left {
        width: 400px;
        border: solid 1px #000;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    #right {
        width: 100%;
        border: solid 1px #000;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both
    }
```